# System format Exception "Invalid cast from System.string to system.drawing.image in data grid view

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have data grid view like this.i am populating data grid view using data source binding[image]

while binding i am getting one extra column emp image ..actually i want to show my image in **`image`** column itself..so i given code like this in load event

```
Dim cd As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select c.cid,c.CompanyName,d.dtId,d.dtName as Department,d.dtPhone as Phone,d.dtEmail as Email,d.empimage from CompanyMaster_tbl c join  DepartmentMaster_tbl d on c.Cid=d.cId order by cid", con.connect)
dt1 = New DataTable
bSource = New BindingSource
adapter.Fill(dt1) 'Filling dt with the information from the DB
bSource.DataSource = dt1
gv.DataSource = bSource
gv.Columns("cid").Visible = False
gv.Columns("dtId").Visible = False
Dim img As New DataGridViewImageColumn
img.HeaderText = "image"
gv.Columns.Insert(6, img)
For i As Integer = 0 To gv.Rows.Count - 1
    gv.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = gv.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value
Next
gv.Columns("empimage").Visible = False
```

actullay here i am copying images from `empimage` column to `image` column ,,then make `empimage` visible false..after saving am calling this method again..that time getting error like this:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the three steps below

1. Adding `image` column
2. copying from `empimage` column to `image` column
3. hiding `empimage` column

Don't add the image column and change your query to assign an alias to the empimage column as below

> select c.cid,c.CompanyName,d.dtId,d.dtName as Department,d.dtPhone as Phone,d.dtEmail as Email,d.empimage as image from CompanyMaster_tbl c join  DepartmentMaster_tbl d on c.Cid=d.cId order by cid

Comment: sir,,if i not add image column in data grid view how i can add image to data grid view cell??

Comment: the sameway how the empimage is getting added, once you bind the datasource the columns will be autogenerated. Did you try changing the code?

Comment: i try this code ,,but while saving image is not getting save,,i think that cell not having image column property.in save button i am taking particular image value like this:Dim image As Image = TryCast(gv.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value, Image)

Comment: this time am getting null value